# Notes deleted after updating to Yosemite

Tags: macos, notes.app

My notes have been deleted after updating the OS on my Macbook Pro from Lion to Yosemite. How can I recover them?

<sup>MacBook Pro (13-inch, Late 2011)</sup>

Comment: did you check the iCloud ?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

1. Go to Finder.
2. Applications.
3. System Preferences.
4. iCloud.
5. Tick the "Notes" box.